# Should I reject suggested edit which write new code

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

In [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16949214) the editor add code that wasn't exists before.

I [search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) but I didn't find relevant reference to that.

I think it can be rejected or approved, but I don't think that's what should be done in edits.

Comment: It should be rejected. 

Drastic changes that attempts to add or modify large parts of the code, should be written as a new answer instead, not as an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code was provided by OP in a comment or an answer to his own question because he didn't realize he could edit, then approve the edit.

Otherwise, the edit might be masking the problem he had and it should be rejected.

This looks like a good rejection to me.

Comment: Yes, I see that it was taken from different answer. In that case I'll mark as causes harm "Taken from different answer"

Comment: Even author of the  edit knew that they adding completely new code based on their edit caption: "Added another option"... Consider rejecting with custom reason and adding comment "post new options as separate answer" for similar cases.